# Remove all elements with specific class if clicked outside of specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working from a continuation of the project that I have started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733259/how-to-prepend-html-into-on-page-element-from-html-onclick-event).

Basically, this is dynamically creating tooltip popups in a relative position to a link when clicked. What I now need to do is have them close when a click is registered anywhere on the page except for an element with the class of "tooltip-dialog". I would like the click to remove all instances of elements with the class of "dialog-anchor" from the DOM. In addition to this, I would like to have only one tooltip popup be allowed active at a time.

I played around with this for several hours yesterday evening, but am unsure of how to approach implementing the intended functionality. I would really appreciate if someone would be willing to take the time to explain to me how to go about this.

Here is the code thus far. Currently, This only generates the new tooltip on click.

```
$(function() { //jquery document.ready

  $('a.tooltip').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    $this.prepend('<div class="dialog-anchor"><div class="dialog-container"><div class="tooltip-dialog"><h4>' + $this.data('title') + '</h4><p>' + $this.data('content') + '</p></div><div class="bg"></div></div></div>');

  });

});
```

Here's what the on page HTML looks like for the links prior to firing the tooltip popup:

```
<a class="tooltip top" data-title="This is a tooltip" data-content="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"></a>
```

Comment: Please Post the relevant html code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a relatively-positioned `.dialog-anchor` element:

```
$this.prepend('<div class="dialog-anchor">...</div>');
```

Add an empty `dialog-overlay` element:

```
$this.prepend('<div class="dialog-overlay"></div>');
$this.prepend('<div class="dialog-anchor">...</div>');
```

Now, in your CSS:

```
.dialog-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.dialog-anchor {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

The dialog box will be above your overlay. The overlay is a transparent layer over your entire screen. Add a click-handler to the overlay:

```
var $overlay = $('<div class="dialog-overlay"></div>');
var $anchor = $('<div class="dialog-anchor">...</div>');
$overlay.on('click', function() {
  $anchor.remove();
});
$this.prepend($overlay);
$this.prepend($anchor);
```

This solution allows you to do other effects like dimming the rest of the page, like this:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Comment: With a little massage, this solution seems to be working great for me now! Thank you very much. One question I do have is:

If I were to design and style up a nice little close button for the active tooltip, would the .closest() method be the appropriate way to run up the DOM tree and kill the parent .dialog-anchor?

Thanks again!!

Comment: Yes, that would do fine.

Comment: Although I would prefer `$anchor.on('click', '.close-button', $anchor.remove)`

Comment: Beautiful! I really appreciate the help/suggestions mate. Thank you very much

Comment: Just ran into a small quirk. While a tooltip is active, clicking inside of it will continue to prepend copies of it into the a.tooltip but clicking the overlay only removes one of these. Is there a simply way to have the overlay click event remove all instances of $anchor?

Comment: Instead of `$anchor.remove()`, do `$('.dialog-anchor').remove()`. Oh, you'll also want to remove the overlays!

Comment: Brilliant! I was using $overlay.remove(); to remove the overlays already, but was having the same issue as with the dialog-anchors. Grabbing it by the class name works perfectly. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to bind a listener to the document to catch events bubbling up, check where they came from and see if that is either a target-class element, or inside a target-class element.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.originalTarget).hasClass('.tooltip-dialog') && !$(e.originalTarget).closest('.tooltip-dialog').length) {
        $('.tooltip-target').remove();
    }
});
```

The upside of this is that it's guaranteed to catch any click event outside of the tooltip.

There are two downsides - first off it will trigger on any click (but click doesn't happen often enough that it's likely to be a problem) and in general, binding events to `document` should be done sparingly, although in this specific case, it is the correct element to bind it to so it's not actually a big downside either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `blur()` jQuery event. It simply does something when the mouse is clicked anywhere outside the element, or even key presses like TAB key http://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
 $(".dialog-anchor").not(".tooltip-dialog").blur(function(){
 //Do something
 });
```